# How do I return an appropriately lifetimed reference to an iterator over struct contents?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I’m trying to implement an iterator over a 2-dimensional grid as below (this is a simplification of a bit more complex setup):

```
struct Grid {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
}

impl Grid {
    fn new(width: usize, height: usize) -> Grid {
        Grid { width, height }
    }

    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> {
        let i = (0..self.height).flat_map(|y: usize| (0..self.width).map(move |x| (x, y)));
        &i
    }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:12:43
   |
12 |         let i = (0..self.height).flat_map(|y: usize| (0..self.width).map(move |x| (x, y)));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 11:13...
  --> src/lib.rs:11:13
   |
11 |     fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> {
   |             ^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &&Grid
              found &&'a Grid
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
  --> src/lib.rs:11:34
   |
11 |     fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I cannot figure out how to return an appropriately lifetimed reference to the iterator. I understand that the lifetime of the iterator must not exceed the lifetime of the underlying `Grid` struct.

Comment: You are thinking way too complicated. You don't want to return `&impl Iterator` but `impl Iterator`. Make that happen and then look again

Comment: Well, that was what I first tried. That gives me "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime" ... "this return type evaluates to the `'static` lifetime..." ... "but this borrow... can't outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body" etc. Tried adding "+ 'a" to annotate a lifetime, then got to "closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function". I'm quite sure the return type needs to be a lifetimed ref.

Comment: use `move` on the `flat_map` closure as well ;)

Comment: Ha, thanks! I posted the working solution below.

Answer (score 3):

The return type must not be a reference. The trick is to add a lifetime specifier for the return type. Also, both closures need to have `move` to capture the ownership of the `self` and `y`.

```
fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + 'a {
    (0..self.height).flat_map(move |y| (0..self.width).map(move |x| (x, y)))
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, if you are using Rust2018, you can elide `'a` and instead use `fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + '_`

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to maintain any references to the original struct here since all the closed-over values implement `Copy`. You just need to extract `height` and `width` from the struct, making a copy as you do so:

```
fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> {
    let Self { height, width } = *self;
    (0..height).flat_map(move |y| (0..width).map(move |x| (x, y)))
}
```